# kind - Kubernetes pods can't pull image from private docker registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kind

I have a problem with a local kind kubernetes cluster I have.

I applied a regcred secret with the relevant details of my private registry and then a deployment file pointing to that registry and uses the relevant secret but it seems like the pods aren't able to pull the image. I tested it on a kubernetes cluster that is not local and the pods are running for the same deployment file and the same yaml file.

deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: db-deployment
  labels:
    app: db-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      name: db-deployment
      labels:
        app: db-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: db-deployment
          image: *** private docker registry ***
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5001
          command: ["python", "flask_main.py"]
      restartPolicy: Always
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: db-deployment
```

I execed to my kind container and then run "crictl pull ***private docker registry***/db:v1" and got the following error:

```
pulling image failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "***private docker registry***/db:v1": failed to resolve reference "***private docker registry***/db:v1": failed to do request: Head https://***private docker registry***/db/manifests/v1: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I tried to add the relevant certificate to C:\Program Data\Docker\certs.d and reboot docker but that didn't help.
What can I do from here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share your `kind: Cluster` config by editing the question?

Comment: Is your private docker registry enabled in the kind cluster configuration? @Yaakov Shami

Answer (score 1):

To add an insecure docker registry, add the file C:\ProgramData\docker\config\daemon.json with the following content:

{
"insecure-registries" : [ "your.private.registry.host" ]
}
and then you need to restart docker.

Comment: I don't have a config folder over there, I only had cli-plugins and I created a certs.d folder. Should I create it as well?

Comment: Yes try that   The problem is with certificate authority

Comment: @YaakovShami Does that solve your problem?

Comment: @AbhijitGaikwad didn't help, I added this JSON file and restarted docker.. still not working.